# How to give to some user permissions only to subfolder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, debian

I have root permissions on my server and I want to give permissions to particular groups and users of it. There is a one case, there is directory tree:

```
  dir1
    ├── subdir1
    ├── subdir2
    ├── subdir3
```

I have three users (user1, user2, user3) - i want each of them to have permissions only to one directory (user1 - subdir1, user2 - subdir2, user3 - subdir3). User1 should not be able to see whats int subdir2 or subdir3, but he cant see that they exist, same with other users and their dirs.

I give persmissions using getfacl and setfacl commands.

What permissions should these users have to dir1 and subdirs?

Comment: (does this question belong to StackOverflow? Voting to move it to ServerFault or SuperUser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To allow all users see list of files in `dir1` set permissions 0755 to this folder

```
$ chmod dir1 0755
```

To separate access to subfolders assign owner to each folder:

```
$ cd dir1

$ chown user1:user1 -R subdir1
$ chown user2:user2 -R subdir2
$ chown user3:user3 -R subdir3
```

Now make subfolders readable only for theirs owners:

```
$ chmod user* 0700
```

Now all users see that folders user* exist, but they can enter only in own folder

**Update**
Sorry, can't format text in comments.

> When I have more users than these three, and I want only these three
>   to be able to enter dir1 - what then?

Then you have to assign them one special group and allow this group to read content of dir1.

Create group `specialusers`

```
$ groupadd specialusers
```

Add users in this group

```
$ usermod -aG specialusers user1
$ usermod -aG specialusers user2
$ usermod -aG specialusers user3
```

Allow `specialusers` to read folder

```
$ chown root:specialusers dir1
$ chmod dir1 0750
```

Now only users from in group `specialusers` can see a list of folders under dir1

Comment: When I have more users than these three, and I want only these three to be able to enter dir1 - what then?

Comment: @pawel Use groups in that case.

Comment: Then you have to assign them one special group and allow this group to read content of dir1.  
  
  Create group `specialusers`  
`$ groupadd specialusers`  
  
Add users in this group  
`$ usermod -aG specialusers user1`  
`$ usermod -aG specialusers user2`  
`$ usermod -aG specialusers user3`  
  
Allow `specialusers` to read folder   
`$ chown root:specialusers dir1`  
`$ chmod dir1 0750`  
  
Now only users from in group `specialusers` can see a list of folders under dir1