# Apache symlinks give 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, apache

I have some projects in /home/novito/Projects that I want Apache to be able to serve.

I have done the following:

```
cd /var/www
sudo ln -s /home/novito/Projects/testphp testphp
```

When I visit `localhost/testphp/index.php`, I get a

> You don't have permission to access /testphp/prova.php on this server.

I have tried doing the following:

```
cd /home/novito/Projects
sudo chmod 755 testphp
```

But I still have the same problem. When doing ls -la, I see the following info for testphp directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) `FollowSymLinks` set …?

Comment: @CBroe wouldn't Nobita get a 404 instead of a 403 if this option weren't set? (just asking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you just tested the permission for testphp directory.

**The complete path** has to be executable by Apache. So you have to do this:

```
$ cd /
$ sudo chmod o+x home
$ sudo chmod o+x home/novito
$ sudo chmod o+x home/novito/Projects
$ sudo chmod o+x home/novito/Projects/testphp
```

Or in a single line:

```
$ sudo chmod o+x /home /home/novito /home/novito/Projects /home/novito/Projects/testphp
```

This will give Apache (and everybody else) the right permissions.

A more comprehensive answer can be found [here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142084/apache-gives-403-forbidden). Worth reading.

Comment: May be better at once use : sudo chmod 775 - R home?

Comment: No, because it will make every single thing executable in the entire /home directory. Not saying it won't work, but it could be... problematic :)

Comment: could be... could be... , who knews)

Comment: Jivan, by doing so aren't we making it so that anybody can execute those folders? How could we just make Apache to be able to do so?

Comment: @Nobita yes anybody can execute. It gets tricky to give the whole path execution permission only for Apache, so I won't plunge in there and advise you to ask a specific question instead (on AskUbuntu, Linux Stack Exchange, or SuperUser for instance)

Comment: Jivan, yes. I should have done that from the very beginning. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Nobita useful information can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110891/how-to-give-to-some-user-permissions-only-to-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

It can be problem with linux permissions or it can be [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) used in [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) directive of virtual host config for apache.